# SQL: How many rows have the largest value for a column

Tags: sql, count, max

I am sure this is a very simple answer, though I have not turned anything up. Most because I am sure I am phrasing the question wrong.

Anyway, lets say I have this very simple table:

Table: `election_candidates`

```
id | candidate_id | election_id | votes
---------------------------------------
1  | 2            | 1           | 3
2  | 5            | 1           | 3
3  | 3            | 1           | 2
```

I need to know if two candidates are tied. So if there is more than one candidate with the most amount of votes for an election.

I know I can use `MAX` function to get the largest value for an election, but is their an easy query to get how many candidates have the MAX for a given election?

I'm using PHP and the Codeigniter framework, though just a general example of a query that could work is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support ANSI-standard window functions.  One way to do this is using `rank()`:

```
select ec.election_id, count(*) as NumTies
from (select ec.*, rank(votes) over (partition by election_id order by votes desc) as seqnum
      from election_candidates ec
     ) ec
where seqnum = 1
group by ec.election_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the winner:

```
SELECT * 
from election_candidates 
ORDER BY votes DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
select e.*
from election_candidates e
inner join (
    select election_id, max(votes) as maxVotes, 
    from election_candidates
    group by election_id
) maxVotesPerElectionId on e.election_Id = maxVotesPerElectionId.election_id
    and e.votes = maxVotesPerElectionId.maxVotes
```

this should get you the candiates (per election) with the max votes.

Answer (score 0):

This will group all elections together, using rank() sort each election by votes cast and list in the order of placement. 
All candidates are listed and displayed on how they did in each election.

```
 DECLARE @T AS TABLE (id INT,candidate_id INT,election_id INT,votes INT)
 INSERT INTO @T VALUES
 (1 ,2,1,3),(2 ,5,1,3),(3 ,3,1,2),(4 ,2,2,3),(5 ,5,3,1),(6 ,6,1,4),(7 ,2,3,3),(8 ,1,4,3),
 (9 ,1,5,2),(10,4,5,3),(11,5,5,3),(12,6,5,4)

 SELECT 
    election_id,
    votes,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY election_id  ORDER BY votes) AS RANKING,
    candidate_id
 FROM @T 
    ORDER BY election_id,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY election_id  ORDER BY votes)
```